# Reusable view holds onto old data

Tags: swift, swiftui

My app is complex, so creating and sharing a small sample app. Basically I have a reusable list row view (ReusableListRowView) which is used by many views across the app, hence I am creating a @State property within the view to pass the data to it and not using a Publisher.

When I first pass the data to ReusableListRowView, it displays that data. But when I pass another data to it's property, ReusableListRowView still displays old data and not the updated data.

In my code below, ContentView has a list and it's first row is where ReusableListRowView is used. 2nd row is to navigate to NewView. Once I navigate to NewView and come back to ContentView, data gets updated and this new data is being passed to ReusableListRowView.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

class DisplayItem: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String

    init(title: String, subtitle: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    public static func == (lhs: DisplayItem, rhs: DisplayItem) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showDisplayData: Bool = false
    @Published var displayData: DisplayItem?
    
    /// This property is just to change the data when view appears. In real app, a query gets executed which updates the data when view appears.
    var value = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var navigateToNextView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.gray.opacity(0.5).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    List {
                        Section {
                            if viewModel.showDisplayData, let displayData = viewModel.displayData {
                                let _ = print("Latest display title in ContentView - \(displayData.title)")
                                ReusableListRowView(displayData: displayData)
                            }
                            
                            VStack {
                                Text("Click to go to next view").font(.body).foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            }.onTapGesture {
                                navigateToNextView = true
                            }
                        } header: {
                            Text("Data update issue")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.displayData = getDisplayItem()
                    viewModel.showDisplayData = true
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $navigateToNextView) {
                NextView().environmentObject(viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func getDisplayItem() -> DisplayItem {
        if viewModel.value == 0 {
            return DisplayItem(title: "Update Me", subtitle: "Both title and subtitle should get updated.")
        } else {
            return DisplayItem(title: "I have been updated", subtitle: "No need to worry.")
        }
    }
}

struct ReusableListRowView: View {
    @State var displayData: DisplayItem
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2.0) {
            let _ = print("Display title in ReusableListRowView - \(displayData.title)")
            Text(displayData.title).font(.body.bold()).foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
            Text(displayData.subtitle).font(.caption).foregroundStyle(Color.secondary)
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                HStack(spacing: 2) {
                    Text("Use back button to go back.").font(.body).foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            } header: {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.value = 1
        }
        .onDisappear {
            viewModel.value = 1
        }
    }
}
```

If you run my code, you will notice, below 2 lines getting printed in console/debug log.

> Latest display title in ContentView - Update Me
> Display title in ReusableListRowView - Update Me

Then tap on 2nd row to navigate to new view and tap on back button in new view to come back to content view. Notice ContentView does have updated data, but ReusableListRowView still shows old data.

> Latest display title in ContentView - I have been updated
> Display title in ReusableListRowView - Update Me

Why is ReusableListRowView holding onto old data and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try using `struct DisplayItem: Hashable, Identifiable ...`
removing the `hash` and `==` stuff. Also you should always use `@State private var  ...`

Comment: Hmm.. I can try using struct instead of class. I was just able to remove @State from ReusableListRowView and convert it to regular var and I was able to fix it that way. BTW why "@State private var..." ? How will I pass the data if I make the property private.

Comment: `ObservableObject` classes work best with publishing `value types` (Int, String,...struct) not
 with reference types `class`.
 As for private state, see
 [State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state)

Comment: In that case, you can change to ObservedObject not State. It's for a different use case.

Comment: you shouldn't have view model classes in SwiftUI, you need to learn to use the View struct hierarchy for your view data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to use @State in `ReusableListRowView`. This state means the row will hold a value on its own, however, this value is passed from the parent, it makes no sense. From my perspective, the row view is for displaying data only. I would prefer to make it a `let`.

```swift
struct ReusableListRowView: View {
    let displayData: DisplayItem
    ...
}
```

Then it should work as expected.

```
Latest display title in ContentView - Update Me
Display title in ReusableListRowView - Update Me
Latest display title in ContentView - I have been updated
Display title in ReusableListRowView - I have been updated
```